# Forward Engineering to SQL Server from MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, forward-engineer

Is possible to forward engineer to SQL Server from MySQL workbench?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2010, when the question was asked, the answer was:

> Not in a straightforward way. You'd need to create a MySQL schema,
> then use some tool to convert it to MSSQL one.

However in 2014 Philip Olson added this comment below:

> [...]MySQL Workbench added a Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL migration
> wizard. You could use it to migrate to MySQL and then execute the
> forward engineer wizard.

I believe this is the correct answer currently.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like this is going to be the only solution.

Comment: Note: After this question was asked, MySQL Workbench added a Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL migration wizard. You could use it to migrate to MySQL and then execute the forward engineer wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Choose forward engineer from the database menu, copy the SQL script it shows you, modify it to make it MSSQL compatible and run it on your MSSQL server.