# Can MySQL Workbench Forward Engineer (Generate DDL) for Relational Databases other than MySQL (such as MS SQL Server, PostGreSQL, Oracle, etc.)

Tags: rdbms, mysql-workbench, erd, forward-engineer

I was under the impression that MySQL Workbench could be used to generate DDL for relational databases other than MySQL.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3391130/forward-engineering-to-sql-server-from-mysql-workbench) from 2010 says no, the only way to do it is to generate DDL for MySQL and then manually convert it.

Has there been any changes in the meantime? Any plugins?

Thank you -- Matthew Moisen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a MySQL Workbench dev and I can tell you firsthand that nothing have changed about this.